# UIView does not appear after calling [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Tags: uiview, ios5

So this one has me stumped....

I show a navigation controller, which after pressing a button sends an NSNotification to it's parent which executes:

```
-(void)dismissModalWithUpload:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(executeUpload:) withObject:notification];
}
```

The modal dialog dismisses, everything is fine there. In the subsequent call (executeUpload) I try to unhide a view which contains a progress indicator to do some other work:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showProgressBar:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

...the trouble is, the progress does not appear until the task in executeUpload is done. I have been trying to background various things to get this working, without any success. Any ideas out there ?

I have also tried to background the upload with:

```
dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.freethinker.uploadQueue", NULL);

dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^{
    [self executeUpload:notification];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I finally got to the bottom of this. The trick is to show the underlying progress view `[progressBaseView setHidden:NO]` *before* dismissing the modal view controller.

The rest of the thinking is correct - all of the heavy lifting occurs in the background, while updating the UI on the main thread.